# Azure Devops: How can I get target branch for a GitHub-based pull request?

Tags: azure, github, azure-pipelines

In my scenario, the pipelines are hosted on Azure, but the repository is hosted on GitHub. We have a functioning pipeline defined which is automatically triggered when a GitHub pull request is created.

What I'd like to have available as a variable is at least the target branch of the pull request, but ideally, any other information about the pull request as well.

For DevOps PRs, Azure defines [a long list of variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services), including `$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)`, which is exactly what I would like to know. However, most of these variables are not defined when the pull request comes from a GitHub repository.

Here's a massively cut-down version of the YAML:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr:
  # These branch names should show up in variables somewhere:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - other_branch
stages:
- stage: test_branches
  displayName: Branch Info
  jobs:
  - job: show_vars
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        clean: true
      - bash: |
          echo "this variable is not defined: $SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_TARGETBRANCHNAME"
          echo "this works, but is not what I need: $BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"
          echo "show all vars, none of these contain anything useful:"
          for var in $(compgen -e); do
            echo $var ${!var};
          done
```

How can I figure out these branch names in my scripts?